# THREE.JS Skybox not displayed on screen

Tags: javascript, web, three.js, 3d, skybox

I am trying to include a skybox to a scene in a web page, so I followed a tutorial I found (https://dev.to/codypearce/how-to-create-a-skybox-with-three-js-2bn8), everything seems to work correctly as my console (on firefox) doesn't display any errors or warning.

First the code creates an array of texture, then assembles the textures in a box and finally adds the box to the scene. I don't have any light in my scene as every objects are visible without any so far (and when I try to add one it doesn't change anything, and the console doesn't show any error either).

I thought it could be a matter of distance of the camera to the skybox so I got the skybox closer to the camera but still nothing.

I put my code down here if you want to see what I did so far. Thanks in advance for your help!

```js
var camera, scene, rendu;
var r, t;

init();

function init() {
    r = 3;
    t = 1.1;
    // ---------- scene et camera --------- //
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70 , window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight , 0.01 , 2000 );
    camera.position.set( 0 , 0 , 4 );
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ));

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    loadSkybox();

    // ---------- rendu ------------- //
    rendu = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true} );
    rendu.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    rendu.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    rendu.setAnimationLoop( animation );
    document.body.appendChild( rendu.domElement );

}

function animation() {
    rendu.render( scene, camera );
}


function createPathStrings(filename) {
    const basePath = "./ulukai/";
    const baseFilename = basePath + filename;
    const fileType = ".png";
    const sides = ["ft", "bk", "up", "dn", "rt", "lf"];
    const pathStrings = sides.map(side => {
      return baseFilename + "_" + side + fileType;
    });

    return pathStrings;

}

function createMaterialArray(filename) {
  const skyboxImagepaths = createPathStrings(filename);
  const materialArray = skyboxImagepaths.map(image => {
    let texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(image);

    return new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
  });

  return materialArray;

}

function loadSkybox() {
    // ----------- skybox -------------- //
    var skyboxImage = "corona";
    skyboxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1000, 1000, 1000);
    skybox = new THREE.Mesh(skyboxGeo, createMaterialArray(skyboxImage));
    scene.add(skybox);
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why don't you use `scene.background = cubeTexture`, where `cubeTexture` is a texture, loaded with [`THREE.CubeTextureLoader()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/loaders/CubeTextureLoader)?

Comment: I didn't know it existed, so I tried this in my init() function:

    const loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
    loader.setPath( 'skybox/' );
    console.log(loader);
    const textureCube = loader.load( [
     'corona_bk.png', 'corona_dn.png',
     'corona_ft.png', 'corona_lf.png',
     'corona_rt.png', 'corona_up.png'
    ] );
    console.log(textureCube);

    scene.background = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, envMap: textureCube , transparent: true } );
    console.log(scene.background);

Comment: console.log(loader) and console.log(textureCube) display an object each but don't specify the types of them
console.log(scene.background) displays a MeshBasicMaterial object type

Comment: `scene.background = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, envMap: textureCube , transparent: true } );` this line is very weird. It has to be something like `scene.background = textureCube;`. Have a look at the source code of this example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap.html ( (< >) button at the bottom-right of the window)

Comment: Thanks! I tried to add and adapt lines of this examples to my init func so I added:
const chemin = 'skybox/corona';
const format = '.png';
const urls = [chemin + '_bk_' + format, chemin + '_dn' + format, chemin + '_ft_' + format, chemin + '_lf' + format, chemin + '_rt_' + format, chemin + '_up' + format ];
const reflectionCube = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load( urls );
const refractionCube = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load( urls );
refractionCube.mapping = THREE.CubeRefractionMapping;
scene.background = reflectionCube;

Comment: As it didn't show any errors in the console I tried to open the examples directly to see what it could look like (I have downloaded the whole three.js repository from github) but it occured a blocking "Cross-Origin Request" while charging the files three.module.js , stats.module.js , Orbitcontrols.js and OBJLoader.js

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=local#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: Thank you very much @prisoner849! I succeeded to display the skybox now! Do you know if their will be something to adapt when I will download my page to my webserver?